# Copy postgres spaces in path

Tags: postgresql, csv

Trying to copy a table to a csv file directly on a network I am connected to. It doesnt work the usual way. My usual way of exporting to csv doesnt work. I assume this is because there are spaces in the path or that I am trying to connect to an external drive over a network. Is it possible to export this table directly to that folder on the network?

This would work on a local drive (I replaced the spaces with a _):

```
COPY schema.table TO 'H:/file/Projects_2130/1114_test_test_test_2016/something_something/foldername/filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

This is what I tried after searching online to do for the network, but it is not the solution.

```
COPY schema.table TO 'H:\\file\\Projects 2130\\1114 test test test 2016\\something something\\foldername\\filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I get the error:

ERROR:  could not open file "...." for writing: No such file or directory
********** Error **********

ERROR: could not open file "....csv" for writing: No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: ```COPY schema.table TO 'H:/file/Projects\ 2130/1114\ test\ test\ test\ 2016/something\ something/foldername/filename.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;``` ?.. escape space with backspace?..

Comment: Nope thats not it.

Comment: is that path available on the server?..

Comment: In my folders I can access it directly as a drive. So I am connected to it. And on the server this folder exists. But I am not sure if that is what you mean if the path is available on the server.

Comment: yes - the question is - does this exact path exist on server ? disk H and all those foders with spaces in names